# Committing Vue component data to vuex store before rendering

Tags: vue.js, vuex, nuxt.js

I’m hoping to solve a problem in a Nuxt app:

I’d like to commit data from a set of components to a vuex store – before rendering the components. I’m aware this may not work the way I’d like, so I’m asking for any other suggestions as well.

My reason is that I need to have a component “report in for duty” with information about its contents and functionality before the page is rendered and the component’s css is loaded.

I’m assuming that loading a component while maintaining display: none and then hiding it again would be a no-no. : )

Can this be solved with the fetch method in nuxt?

Happy to get a codesandbox going if this isn’t clear enough.

Comment: Have you looked at Vue render functions? You have much more control over rendering with that method.

Comment: What is the data you need to commit before render? Can you use asyncData?

Comment: @Andrew1325 It's actually static data set by a team member for every section of a page while in the design process -- simple strings and numbers to identify the section type. So it's non-reactivity should be helpful in this case. Looking into both asyncData and render functions now.

Comment: The data does, however need to go to the store for global access.

Comment: I would say asyncData should do the job for you.

Comment: Looks like the `fetch` method is apparently very much like `asyncData`, but for working with the store. Workin' on it!